# Kommasetzung bei „und auch weil“?

Tags: punctuation, comma, parenthesis

Wie würde man folgenden Satz korrekt interpungieren?

> In der folgenden Beschreibung beschränke ich mich der Übersichtlichkeit halber und auch weil es für die Fragestellung der vorliegenden Arbeit relevant ist nur auf deutsche Abteilungen.

Meine erste Theorie war, dass überhaupt keine Kommas gesetzt werden müssen, ich konnte zumindest keinen klaren Nebensatz ausmachen. Allerdings ist der Satz ganz ohne Satzzeichen doch sehr lang und unübersichtlich zu lesen.

Ich hatte in Erwägung gezogen, dass der Teil mit *weil* eventuell in Kommas eingerahmt werden könnte, weil es sich um einen Nebensatz handeln könnte.

> … und auch, weil es für die Fragestellung der vorliegenden Arbeit relevant ist, nur auf deutsche Abteilungen.

Allerdings lässt sich dieser „Nebensatz“ nicht weglassen, ohne das der Satz grammatikalisch entstellt wird, und auch das *und* davor scheint mir eher auf einen gleichgestellten Satzteil hinzudeuten.

Mein aktuell beste Theorie ist, das ganze Konstrukt als Einschub zu betrachten:

> In der folgenden Beschreibung beschränke ich mich, der Übersichtlichkeit halber und auch weil es für die Fragestellung der vorliegenden Arbeit relevant ist, nur auf deutsche Abteilungen.

Kann eventuell jemand aufklären, was für ein Konstrukt in diesem Satz vorliegt (Nebensatz? kein Nebensatz?) und wie ich die Satzzeichen korrekt setzen muss?

Comment: Du kannst es auch mit einem Gedankenstrich versuchen – was mir in deinem Satz sogar am besten im Vergleich zu allen Alternativen gefällt  – und damit den ganzen Einschub vom eigentlichen Textfluss trennen. Man erkennt klar, wo der Hauptteil ist und was die zusätzliche Information ist. Und es erleichtert dadurch das Lesen ungemein.

Answer (score 8):

Das Problem rührt daher, daß der Nebensatz (*weil es … relevant ist*) parallel zu einer anderen Konstruktion (*der Übersichtlichkeit halber*) steht. Hier gilt eine Sonderregelung (§ 74 E2 der Amtlichen Regelung):

> Wenn eine beiordnende Konjunktion wie *und*, *oder* (§ 72) Satzglieder oder Teile von Satzgliedern mit Nebensätzen verbindet, so steht zwischen den Bestandteilen einer solchen Reihung kein Komma. Gegenüber dem übergeordneten Satz sind die Teile der Reihung nur dann mit Komma abgetrennt, wenn der Nebensatz anschließt, nicht aber, wenn das Satzglied bzw. ein Teil eines Satzgliedes anschließt:
>   …
>   *Bei großer Dürre oder wenn der Föhn weht, ist das Rauchen hier streng verboten.*
>   …

Somit muß es heißen, wenn man nicht das Ganze als Einschub betrachtet (was auch möglich ist):

> In der folgenden Beschreibung beschränke ich mich der Übersichtlichkeit halber und auch weil es für die Fragestellung der vorliegenden Arbeit relevant ist, nur auf deutsche Abteilungen.

Ob das schön aussieht, ist eine andere Frage. Ich würde empfehlen, den Satz umzuformulieren. Ein Vorschlag:

> In der folgenden Beschreibung beschränke ich mich auf deutsche Abteilungen. Dies dient der Übersichtlichkeit und entspricht der Fragestellung dieser Arbeit.

Comment: Meiner Meinung nach handelt es sich um einen Einschub, da er weggelassen werden könnte. Das erste Komma würde ich demzufolge wie folgt setzen: "In der folgenden Beschreibung beschränke ich mich der Übersichtlichkeit halber, und auch weil es für die Fragestellung der vorliegenden Arbeit relevant ist, nur auf deutsche Abteilungen."

Comment: @nixda: Man kann verschiedene Teile als Einschub betrachten (eine Variante schon in der Frage, eine andere bei dir), man muß es aber nicht. In jedem Fall ist der Satz stilistisch nicht sehr schön. :-)

Comment: @nixda warum nicht als Antwort?

Comment: Weil mir a) die Paragraphen fehlen würden und b) Chirlu's Antwort es treffender zusammenfasst :-)

Answer (score -1):

Richtig ist: In der folgenden Beschreibung beschränke ich mich der Übersichtlichkeit halber, und auch weil es für die Fragestellung der vorliegenden Arbeit relevant ist, nur auf deutsche Abteilungen.

Comment: Und woher kommt die Erkenntnis, dass es nur so richtig ist und nicht bspw wie in den anderen antworten diskutiert?